# What does Trap Queen means?

Tags: idioms, translation, slang

I'm new in learning English, so I want to know more about idioms and some words that I can't understand.

**What is the meaning of trap queen?**

And how and when the situation we can say that. If you have an example, it would be better to me to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: If the answers satisfy your question, please mark one as correct. If not, then edit your question with further information for better answers.

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on the context in which you use this term.

1) Trap Queen might refer to a song by Fetty Wap

> She my **trap queen**

And in that case Trap is a place where drugs are sold.

---

2) A girl with large trapezius muscles.

> Look at that girl hitting the gym, she's a real **trap queen**

---

3) the person is a queen for traps, with traps meaning boys dressing up as girls, mostly in anime.

> She is so cute, but she is a **trap queen**, so she is really a he.

---

4) @katatahito's answers is also correct, a girl that is very loyal can be called a trap queen.

> My girl will always be with me. She is my **trap queen**!

Comment: NIce work. Absent any other context, I might have assumed it was a chess ploy.

Comment: Didn't think of that. But that is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

This phrase is exclusively used as slang (slang from AAVE as far as I can tell), so it's exact meaning can be hard to define. [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trap%20Queen) has several entries, and a lot of them have somewhat opposite meanings.

In general though:

> A witty or street-smart female, usually with an urban flavor or appeal, who is loyal (potentially to a fault) and resourceful.